# pgp_sym_encrypt postgres perf issue

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres 12 with pgp_sym_encrypt.  It works.  But encrypting a column in a very large table is taking days.  Anyone else have experience making pgp_sym_encrypt faster?  I am inserting/selecting into a new table to avoid slowness with and update in place.  No where clause, really not much to tune that I can see.

To pull 10,000 rows for example takes 35 secs.
select
encode(pgp_sym_encrypt(col1,'KEY',' cipher-algo=aes256'),'hex') as col1
from tablea limit 10000

To pull 10000 rows w/o the function takes just milliseconds.
select
col1
from tablea limit 10000

There are a billion rows.  I think that works out to 972 hours to encrypt this one column in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PGP uses intentionally-slow hashing (although not all that slow) to make it harder to "brute force" weak passwords. You can get rid of this, or weaken it, by changing s2k-mode or s2k-count.  Of course you should give it a lot of thought before intentionally weakening your own encryption.

```
pgp_sym_encrypt(col1, 'KEY', 'cipher-algo=aes256, s2k-mode=1')
```